# A better solution than iterrows for comparing values between different datasets

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have been using `iterrows()` to compare column values *between* two data sets and merge rows where certain conditions are met, however this is taking way to long. Is there a better way I can do this without iterating?

This is the full function

```
def find_peak_matches(lncRNA, CAGE):
"""isolates CAGE peaks that match an lncRNA"""

lncRNA['promoter_start'] = lncRNA['promoter_start'].apply(pd.to_numeric).astype('int32')
lncRNA['promoter_stop'] = lncRNA['promoter_stop'].apply(pd.to_numeric).astype('int32')
CAGE['peak_start'] = CAGE['peak_start'].apply(pd.to_numeric).astype('int32')
CAGE['peak_stop'] = CAGE['peak_stop'].apply(pd.to_numeric).astype('int32')
peak_matches = pd.DataFrame()
for i, row in lncRNA.iterrows():
    mask = (
        (CAGE['chr'] == row['chr']) & \
        (row['promoter_start'] <= CAGE['peak_start']) & \
        (row['promoter_stop'] >= CAGE['peak_stop'])
    )#finds peaks in lncRNA promoters
    matches = CAGE[mask].dropna() #isolates only the peak matches
    if len(matches) == 0: #if no matches found continue
        continue
    merged = pd.merge(
        row.to_frame().T, matches, 
        on=['chr']
    ) #merges rows that meet mask conditions
    peak_matches = pd.concat(
        [peak_matches, merged],
        ignore_index=True
    ) #creates a new df from all the merged rows   

logging.debug('found peak matches')
return (peak_matches)
```

This is a sample lncRNA dataset:

```
name   chr    promoter_start    promoter_stop    info
lnc1    1        1                10              x
lnc2    1       11                20              y
lnc3    1       21                30              z
```

sample CAGE:

```
ID      chr    peak_start    peak_stop 
peak1   1        3             7            
peak2   1        15            17            
peak3   1        4             6            
peak4   2        6             9
```

Desired output:

```
name   chr    promoter_start    promoter_stop    info     ID    peak_start    peak_stop
lnc1   1            1                10            x      peak1       3             7
lnc1   1            1                10            x      peak3       4             6
lnc2   1            11               20            y      peak2       15            17
```

The real datasets contain around 200k rows each, so my current code is taking way too long. I am trying to merge rows where the peak/promoter have the same chr value and the peak start/stop falls in-between the promoter start/stop. Any advice to optimize this? I am fairly knew to python so I have no idea what the best ways of doing things are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have better luck doing all of the heavy lifting before you put the data into `pandas` where you can be a bit more selective about the number of comparisons you need to do--despite the fact that you will give up on some of the numpy accelerants in `pandas`.  I cooked up the example below using `namedtuples` as a convenience and did all the comparisons before making the data frame.  With bogus data of 200K x 200K, it cooks in about 30 seconds on my machine and gets 10M rows of matches, which is **entirely** dependent on the diversity of the random data I used.  YMMV.

There's probably more "left on the floor" here.  Some smart sorting (aside from binning by 'chr' that I did) might go further.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import namedtuple, defaultdict
from random import randint
from itertools import product

# structures
rna = namedtuple('rna', 'name chr promoter_start promoter_stop info')
cage = namedtuple('cage', 'ID chr peak_start peak_stop')
row = namedtuple('row', 'name chr promoter_start promoter_stop info ID peak_start peak_stop')

# some data entry from post to check...
rnas = [rna('inc1',1,1,10,'x'), rna('inc2',1,11,20,'y'), rna('inc1',1,21,30,'z')]
cages = [cage('peak1',1,3,7), cage('peak2',1,15,17), cage('peak3',1,4,6), cage('peak4',2,6,9)]

result_rows = [row(r.name, r.chr, r.promoter_start, r.promoter_stop, r.info, c.ID, c.peak_start, c.peak_stop)
                for r in rnas for c in cages if
                r.chr == c.chr and
                r.promoter_start <= c.peak_start and
                r.promoter_stop  >= c.peak_stop]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=result_rows)
print(df)
print()

# stress test
# big fake data
rnas = [rna('xx', randint(1,1000), randint(1,50), randint(10,150), 'yy') for t in range(200_000)]
cages = [cage('pk', randint(1,1000), randint(1,50), randint(10,150))     for t in range(200_000)]

# group by chr to expedite comparisons
rna_dict = defaultdict(list)
cage_dict = defaultdict(list)
for r in rnas:
    rna_dict[r.chr].append(r)
for c in cages:
    cage_dict[c.chr].append(c)

print('fake data made')

# use the chr's that are keys in the rna dictionary and make all comparisions...
result_rows = []
for k in rna_dict.keys():
    result_rows.extend([row(r.name, r.chr, r.promoter_start, r.promoter_stop, r.info, c.ID, c.peak_start, c.peak_stop)
                for r in rna_dict.get(k) for c in cage_dict.get(k) if
                r.promoter_start <= c.peak_start and
                r.promoter_stop  >= c.peak_stop])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=result_rows)
print(df.head(5))
print(df.info())
```

#### Outputs:

```
   name  chr  promoter_start  promoter_stop info     ID  peak_start  peak_stop
0  inc1    1               1             10    x  peak1           3          7
1  inc1    1               1             10    x  peak3           4          6
2  inc2    1              11             20    y  peak2          15         17

fake data made
  name  chr  promoter_start  promoter_stop info  ID  peak_start  peak_stop
0   xx  804              34             35   yy  pk          36         11
1   xx  804              34             35   yy  pk          39         11
2   xx  804              34             35   yy  pk          37         14
3   xx  804              34             35   yy  pk          34         28
4   xx  804              34             35   yy  pk          39         20
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10280046 entries, 0 to 10280045
Data columns (total 8 columns):
name              object
chr               int64
promoter_start    int64
promoter_stop     int64
info              object
ID                object
peak_start        int64
peak_stop         int64
dtypes: int64(5), object(3)
memory usage: 627.4+ MB
None
[Finished in 35.4s]
```

#### From DataFrame --> namedtuple

A couple options below... researched the same thing and picked up a couple examples.  You can use `pd.itertuples` below to peel them out and put them into namedtuples.  However, it appears to do only positional match.  So BE CAREFUL.  Note the second example is jacked.  Pandas also appears to do its own sort of named row thing that may work just as well.  (Last example).  I haven't tinkered with it much, but it appears to be addressable by names internally, which is nice just like namedtuple.

```
In [22]: df                                                                     
Out[22]: 
   name  chr  promoter_start  promoter_stop info
0  lnc1    1               1             10    x
1  lnc2    1              11             20    y
2  lnc3    1              21             30    z

In [23]: rna = namedtuple('rna', 'name chr promoter_start promoter_stop info')  

In [24]: rows = [rna(*t) for t in df.itertuples(index=False)]                   

In [25]: rows                                                                   
Out[25]: 
[rna(name='lnc1', chr=1, promoter_start=1, promoter_stop=10, info='x'),
 rna(name='lnc2', chr=1, promoter_start=11, promoter_stop=20, info='y'),
 rna(name='lnc3', chr=1, promoter_start=21, promoter_stop=30, info='z')]

In [26]: rna = namedtuple('rna', 'name chr info promoter_start promoter_stop')  # note:  wrong

In [27]: rows = [rna(*t) for t in df.itertuples(index=False)]                   

In [28]: rows                                                                   
Out[28]: 
[rna(name='lnc1', chr=1, info=1, promoter_start=10, promoter_stop='x'),
 rna(name='lnc2', chr=1, info=11, promoter_start=20, promoter_stop='y'),
 rna(name='lnc3', chr=1, info=21, promoter_start=30, promoter_stop='z')]

In [29]: # note the above is mis-aligned!!!                                     


In [32]: rows = [t for t in df.itertuples(name='row', index=False)]             

In [33]: rows                                                                   
Out[33]: 
[row(name='lnc1', chr=1, promoter_start=1, promoter_stop=10, info='x'),
 row(name='lnc2', chr=1, promoter_start=11, promoter_stop=20, info='y'),
 row(name='lnc3', chr=1, promoter_start=21, promoter_stop=30, info='z')]

In [34]: type(rows[0])                                                          
Out[34]: pandas.core.frame.row

In [35]: rows[0].chr                                                            
Out[35]: 1

In [36]: rows[0].info                                                           
Out[36]: 'x'
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to convert from a dataframe to namedtouples? I do lots of modifications with pandas before getting to this point, but I like this approach.

Comment: Added to answer.  Not too much experience there, but found a few things...

Answer (score 0):

You can merge all `lncRNA` and `CAGE` dataframes and then filter it with `df.query`.

For example:

```
df = lncRNA.merge(CAGE, on='chr')
df = df.query('(promoter_start <= peak_start) & (promoter_stop >= peak_stop)')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   name  chr  promoter_start  promoter_stop info     ID  peak_start  peak_stop
0  lnc1    1               1             10    x  peak1           3          7
2  lnc1    1               1             10    x  peak3           4          6
4  lnc2    1              11             20    y  peak2          15         17
```

Comment: merging the full dfs gets very memory intensive. Taking a similar approach of merge first then filter elsewhere in my code resulted in the server killing it and is why I started using masks in the first place

Comment: @keenan Maybe you can merge/filter step by step? First merge/fiter only `chr=1`, then `chr=2` etc...